# Why are JNI calls to native methods slower than similar methods in sun.misc.Unsafe?

Tags: java, performance, java-native-interface, unsafe

I'm developing a JNI implementation similar to sun.misc.Unsafe but with extended memory management.

Why are the call times of native methods from sun.misc.Unsafe and from my developed library extremely different?

Some numbers:
sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt(address) takes ~1ns
when my similar method takes ~10ns

Both implementations are quite the same, following the source code of OpenJDK, just returning the variable by pointer. Both are registered in the same manner.

How can I speed up JNI calls? What makes Unsafe performance so special?

Thanks,
Yury/

Answer (score 15):

If you look for the source of the native methods in the Unsafe class you will find it does not use JNI implementations.  Instead, Unsafe methods are inlined as machine code. `getInt(long)` for example becomes one machine code instruction.

For this reason, you can't write a JNI method which is as fast as using Unsafe, without changing the JVM so it inlines the machine code.

Comment: What I found in openJDK that Unsafe actually are native, and written on C++. See hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp
My code actually only one line of assembly
` mov eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]
 ret 0`

Comment: Normal native methods are not inlined. The native methods in Unsafe can be. BTW: I can't find the implementation for `getInt` and similar simple methods, only the more complex ones.

Comment: Yes, you was right. Unsafe actually inlined as intrinsic.

Code of getInt easy to find in vm/prims/unsafe.cpp
DEFINE_GETSETOOP(jint, Int);
then
  GET_FIELD(obj, offset, jboolean, v);
and then<br/>
#define GET_FIELD(obj, offset, type_name, v) \
  oop p = JNIHandles::resolve(obj); \
  type_name v = *(type_name*)index_oop_from_field_offset_long(p, offset)