# how to keep the received little-endian data as is in Java?

Tags: java

My Java application will receive **little-endian short[]** data through **socket** communication. Java by default is **big-endian**. But I want to **keep** these shorts in **little-endian**.

If I define a **short[]** to receive the data, will the Java **automatically** **convert** them from little-endian to big-endian when the data is put into the short[]?

do I need to do anything to **keep** the received data in the format of **little-endian**?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827398/converting-byte-array-values-in-little-endian-order-to-short-values?

Comment: I don't think so. I am not asking how to convert. I am asking whether Java will automatically convert little-endian to big-endian when little-endian data is put into a normal defined short[] which by default is big-endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary**

Java will not automatically convert bytes to a short, although you can explicitly tell Java to convert them.  You cannot force Java to interpret its own shorts as little-endian numbers. You can, however, write Java shorts as little-endian shorts.

**Detail**

When you say that you're receiving an array of little-endian shorts, I'm assuming that you mean that you're receiving a series of bytes, that you divide the series into pairs, and that the first of the pair is the least-significant byte of a short and the second of which is the most-significant byte.

I don't believe that Java will know how to interpret those bytes unless you explicitly tell it.

For example, if you use [`java.io.DataInputStream.readShort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readShort%28%29) it will read "the next two bytes of this input stream, interpreted as a signed 16-bit number" - and, while this documentation doesn't say, it will interpret the short in the Java way, which is big-endian.

As noted in the comment, if you wish to read a little-endian short into a Java short, you may use [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html): [`wrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28%29) the byte array, set the [`order`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28%29) to [`LITTLE_ENDIAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#LITTLE_ENDIAN), and invoke [`getShort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort%28%29). However, this will store the data as a Java short, which is big-endian. You cannot change that storage format.

You can, however, write a Java short as a little-endian short using the same [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html): [`wrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28%29) the byte array, set the [`order`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28%29) to [`LITTLE_ENDIAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#LITTLE_ENDIAN), and invoke [`putShort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort%28%29).