# Standard Java library for converting endianness of primitive types + uuid

Tags: java, shared-libraries, static-libraries, endianness

I would like to ask if there is already a standard Java library that implements the following two things:

1. converting between endlessness standard Java primitive types + UUID.
2. lossless conversion between signed and unsigned standard Java primitive types. By lossless I mean for example that converting from signed short to unsigned short then the result could be signed Integer.

If such exists then what is the name of that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  use the ByteSwapper from here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Utilityforbyteswappingofalljavadatatypes.htm.

Or alternatively, use the ByteBuffer and specify the endianness with order(), as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14827440/1067124 (copied below)

> With [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) you may specify the endianness you want: [order()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29).
>
> ByteBuffer have methods to extract data as byte, char, [getShort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort%28%29), [getInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28%29), long, double...
>
> Here's an example how to use it:
>
> ```
> ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
> bb.order( ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
> while( bb.hasRemaining()) {
>    short v = bb.getShort();
>    /* Do something with v... */
> }
> ```

Comment: many thanks, basically with the ByteBuffer you can do all of that. :)

Comment: You're welcome @Tito. Please mark the answer Accepted if it helped you :)