# Designing an app with frequent JNI calls on Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am building an Android app that integrates with a 3rd party library that is provided as a native library (.so file).

The app would need to use functionality from the native library at around 0-30 JNI calls per second.

Although the function calls are non-blocking and return almost immediately, i am wondering whether this design should be avoided to begin with, or the overhead of frequent JNI calls in practice can be used?

I have read a similar question here: [What makes JNI calls slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699020/what-makes-jni-calls-slow)

But besides that, i couldn't find too many numbers regarding JNI performance.

Answer (score 2):

On a device I looked at a couple years back, calling an empty static no-arg method in Java took 56ns, while calling the same through JNI took about 250ns.  (Calls got a bit slower in Ice Cream Sandwich -- was 200ns in Honeycomb.)

People tend to fixate on the "it's 5x as expensive" part.  What matters for your application is that the 30 JNI calls would incur less than 8 microseconds of overhead.

It's not worth worrying about unless you're calling it thousands (or tens of thousands) of times per second.