# What makes JNI Object allocation so slow?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I benchmarked a code that allocates 1 million java objects with

1. `env->NewObject`
2. `env->AllocObject`, `env->SetLongField`

To my surprise, the code took 250ms and 125ms to execute respectively. This is 10-5x slower than what an equivalent java program would take!

The overhead of the JNI call is also order of magnitude larger than the one mentioned in [What makes JNI calls slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699020/what-makes-jni-calls-slow) (which goes in the opposite direction `java -> Native`).

What makes it so slow? Doesn't C have direct access to Java heap?

Alternatively, is there a more efficient way to pass data from C to java trough JNI?

The java code:

```java
public class Main { 
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("main"); 
   }
 
   private native void bench();

   static void bench_java() {
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) new Number(i);
      System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now); 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main().bench(); 
   }
}

public class Number {
   long j;

   public Number(long j) {
      this.j = j;
   }
}
```

The c code:

```c
#include "jni.h"  
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <sys/time.h>

 

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_bench(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   struct timespec start, end;

   jclass    cls  = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Number");
   jmethodID init = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(J)V");

   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
   for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, init, 0);
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

   printf("Time elapsed %lu ms\n", (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000);
   return;
}
```

Comment: I haven't profiled this but there are a couple things that come to mind. Function call overhead in c, local ref bookkeeping overhead, no way to jit to improve efficiency /inline constructors.

Comment: I think we can rule out ref bookkeeping overhead since adding `DeleteLocalRef` didn't improve the performance.

Comment: I don't see how that rules out any bookkeeping overhead. The local references still have to be created. Adding `DeleteLocalRef` calls only ensures that you don't overflow the local reference table.

Comment: A thing to keep in mind that JNI has a lot of indirections. Like when you call `NewObject()`, that is a JNI-specific call, going to [`jni_NewObject`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/fb7064dc63f9/src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp#l1104) presumably doing some extra check already, and then going to [`jni_invoke_nonstatic()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/fb7064dc63f9/src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp#l984) for invoking the constructor, which is still JNI-specific and rather generic, so it may be far more complicated with more checks than what the JVM would do itself.

Comment: How do you know `for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) new Number(i);` wasn't entirely optimized away?